# Ideal inductor AC current LTspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, ltspice

I am simulating an ideal inductor in LTSpice connected to a 1Vpk 50Hz sine wave and 1 ohm resistor.

The current through the inductor seems really low, at peak being around 3.2mA

As the current through the inductor should be the integral of the voltage multiplied by the inductance it seems that this should be higher. So why is it this low?

[image]

Comment: Have you calculated the impedance at 50 kHz of a 1 Henry inductor?

Comment: 50kHz? this should be 50Hz?

Comment: Not that it matter in magnitude in this case, but you're quite like **not** simulating an **ideal** inductor, unless you noticed and nullified the standard 1mΩ series resistance for inductors in LTspice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1H is a rather large inductor, and 1V is a rather low voltage, so it seems reasonable to me.

The impedance of the inductor alone is \$2\pi fL\$ or about 314 ohms at 50Hz, so R1 isn't doing much and the current will be about 3.2mA.

Remember, the magnitude of the total impedance of an inductive and resistive component in series is \$\sqrt{X_L^2+R^2}\$ so unless the two components are fairly close in magnitude the larger one tends to dominate.

Answer (score 0):

What you've essentially done is create a low pass filter, at higher frequencies the load of the inductance and resistance increases, so less current flows:

This means at 50Hz the sine wave is being attenuated so the answer is correct.

[image]

Try different frequencies and note the difference in current, it will follow the graph above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your inductance is huge so it takes a long time for current to change through it for a given applied voltage. It takes long enough that the sinusoid source reverses direction before the current can ever get too high.

1 Ohm is pretty small, but 1H or 1F are enormous. uH and uF are more common and really big heavy things can be mH or mF.